# Is it possible to use switch statement when compering fragments with instanceof

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have got several fragments that are replaced inside layout. Sometimes I need to find out the object of current fragment inside layout. Here's how I am doing it:

```
Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

if (currentFragment instanceof Fragment1) {
     //...
} else if (currentFragment instanceof Fragment2) {
     //...
} else if (currentFragment instanceof Fragment3) {
     //...
} else if (currentFragment instanceof Fragment4) {
    //...
}
```

Is it possible to use switch statemet in this case?

Comment: You may consider refactoring this to the Visitor-Pattern.

Comment: `instanceof` tends to indicate a bit of a design problem: code shouldn't need to know the specific subtype of an object it is dealing with. `Fragment` should have a method which the subclasses can override.

Comment: What will you be doing with the fragments?

Comment: Not possible with java - but possible in Kotlin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use switch. Use the Visitor-Pattern. Or at least something similar:

In your Fragment, implement a method for the Activity to call

```
interface IFragmentSpecificStuffHandler{
    void visit( Activity visitor); // You may use another Interface that your Activity implements to allow the Fragment to make specific callbacks or initiate state-changes in the activity specific to this functionality.
}
```

Your Fragments would implement that interface with the specific stuff to be done.

In the Activity you would replace your if/else by:

```
Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
// Maybe check if the Fragment actually implements the interface before casting or enclose in try/catch
((IFragmentSpecificStuffHandler)currentFragment).visit(this);
```

You should consider better naming, though.

So basically you push the responsibility to know what to do for each Fragment-Variation to that Fragment-Variation. This has some advantages:

- Your Activity code is cleaner (no ugly if/elseif/else)
- No instable checks for class equality
- If you later add another Fragment-Type you just need to implement the interface there ( no need to change Activity code).
- ...

If you want to or have to keep that code in the Activity, you can go for a double dispatch:

```
interface IVisitor{
    void visit( Fragment1 f ); // <- These correspond to your "if instanceof" - branches
    void visit( Fragment2 f );
    void visit( Fragment3 f );
}

interface IVisitable{
     void accept( IVisitor visitor );
}
```

Inside your Activity, which implements `IVisitor`:

```
public void visit(Fragment1 f){
     //code for Fragment1
     // what you would have written inside the if-body
}

public void visit(Fragment2 f){
     //code for Fragment2
}

public void visit(Fragment3 f){
     //code for Fragment3
}
```

On the spot where your if/elsif/else would have been:

```
Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
((IVisitable)currentFragment).accept(this); // Dispatch #1
```

In your Fragments you'll implement `IVisitable`:

```
//... we are in Fragment1
public void accept( IVisitor visitor ){ 
    visitor.visit(this); /* Dispatch #2 just callback into visitor, 
                          * will automatically call the correct 
                          * visit( x ) impl. in Activity.*/
}
```

The latter approach is the exact implementation of the "Visitor Pattern" and has some advantages in visibility of Activity-Fields. Drawback is in case of a later added Fragment aside from creating that you'll have to change an interface and touch the activity. Personally I often find the "shortcut" version in the beginning of the answer is sufficient but that depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly, no.

As they say in the switch documentation,

> A switch works with the
>   byte, short, char, and int primitive data types. It also works with
>   enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types), the String class, and a
>   few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character,
>   Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in Numbers and Strings).

This is because the switch needs a "`Case`" value that is static and that can never change.

For example you will be able to do something like this:

```
switch (month) {
        case 1:  break;
...
```

But you won't be able to do something like this:

```
switch (month) {
        case object.intvalue: break;
...
```

because the value of intvalue is not static.

The same concept is with the `istanceof`.

Comment: Note that `foo instanceof Bar` isn't the same thing as `foo.getClass().equals(Bar.class)`: the former returns true if `foo` is a subtype of `Bar` too.

Comment: @AndyTurner Oh, so in switch statement istanceof is allowed as case clause?

Comment: No, that's not what I said at all. I am pointing out that you can't use `Map.get` to emulate the same behaviour, because that's based on equality of classes. And equality is more brittle than `instanceof`, since it requires the *exact* class.

Comment: Oh ok! sorry I missunderstood your sentence. I remove the example since it can point someone to the wrong solution

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use switch case in this because switch case works on single expression which can give multiple values. Problem you are trying to solve is different you want different expressions with set of values(True/False). In this case you need to evaluate different expression every time which can be true or false.